# membership defaultProvider Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET MVC site to use LDAP.  I feel like I have everything set up right, but Membership.ValidateUser keeps returning false when I am expecting it to return true.  I've read some documentation, like for example [this one on AD membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), but one thing I want to make sure I completely understand as I am troubleshooting is this:

Is the defaultProvider attribute value something specific provided by Microsoft? Or is it just an arbitrary name, and we can call it anything?

This is my current web.config setup:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://dc1.dc2.dc3.dc4/DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3,DC=dc4" /
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: You declare your providers (i.e. AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider) then you define one of them as default via the defaultProvider. If you put in defaultProvider something else than a provider defined it will not work as expected.

Comment: @StfBln That makes complete sense.  Thank you very much.